# Anchor link takes two clicks to fire the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dataTextBox" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<a class='new_message' onclick='focusMethod();' tabindex='-1' href='#dataTextBox"> New Message</a>";
```

Jquery function:

```
function focusMethod() {
        $('[class=new_message]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
        });
    }
```

When i click the anchor link the focus should go to the input text box. But it is taking 2 clicks to perform.

My scenarios are:

1. onclick is used in anchor tag to prevent default behaviour i.e firing the href.
2. I am building an accessible form so i need the href with value (so i wont be able to use href="#")
3. If i use just the click event handler without the function it is not being fired( instead href is fired and focus is not going to textbox)

It takes 2 clicks because the function focusMethod is fired first and then event handler is attached.
Is there any way to avoid performing the function "focusmethod' and only perform click event handler?

Comment: i mean... you have a click event, that binds a click event, that then finally performs your action. so you have to click a second time for the second event to occur, because it didn't exist on the first click... *logic*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your method `focusMethod` is *binding* a new click event which is then executing next time you click that element. Just remove the inline click event `onclick='focusMethod();'` as it's not needed. Then instead of a function you can just do:

```
$('[class=new_message]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
});
```

**Edit:**

Since your element is dynamic you need to use `$(document).on(...)` instead, otherwise the selector `$(...).click(..)` isn't going to find the element as it wouldn't exist when setting up the click event binding.

Below is a basic example with the element being dynamically created:

```js
$(document).on("click", "[class=new_message]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
});

$("body").html("<a class='new_message' tabindex='-1' href='#dataTextBox'> New Message</a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: does it matter where the click event code should go? because the click event handler is not being fired

Comment: @raj Generally you put event handlers inside `document.ready`.

Comment: Even though if i place my code in document.ready it doesn't work. The anchor link is generated dynamically. Is there anything to do with it.

Comment: @raj It is. In that case you need to do `$(document).on('click', '[class=new_message]'){ ... });`. Otherwise it doesn't find the element as when trying to bind, as it doesn't find it through the selector `[class=new_message]` initially so [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> It takes 2 clicks because the function focusMethod is fired first and then event handler is attached.

You've correctly identified the issue, you're requiring a click to run the function that contains the jQuery `.click` function. Just remove the `focusMethod()` function (and `onclick`) altogether.

```js
$('.new_message').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
});
```

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="dataTextBox" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<a class='new_message' tabindex='-1' href='#dataTextBox'>New Message</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Firefox. Does it matter where the click event code should go. Can i place the code anywhere in the js file?

Answer (score 0):

1. remove click event in HTML.
2. use only class.click in JS.
3. for href you are opening with single quote but closing with double quote.

```js
$('[class=new_message]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
});
```

```html
<a class='new_message' tabindex='-1' href='#dataTextBox'> New Message</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If **@Spencer Wieczorek** answer(accepted answer) is not working for someone then you should just need a simple replace 'click' to 'turbolinks:click'.

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:click", "[class=new_message]", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("clicked");
  $($(this).attr('href')).focus();
});
```